# Quadratic Functions

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider the strictly convex quadratic function $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^tPx - q^tx + r,$ where $P \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a positive definite matrix, $q \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $r \in \mathbb{R}.$ Let $\mathcal{H} := \{H: H \text{ is a }k- \text{dimensional subspace in } \mathbb{R}^n\}.$ Clearly, the restriction of $f$ to any $H \in \mathcal{H}$ is again a strictly convex function. For any $H \in \mathcal{H},$ we will use $x_H$ to denote the *unique* optimal point of the following problem

\begin{equation*}
\underset{x \in H}{\text{min.}} \;  f(x).
\end{equation*}

Now consider the map, $\psi(H) = x_H.$

Prove / Disprove: The map $\psi$ is bijective.

Remark: It is assumed that $P$ is invertible and $q \neq \mathbf{0}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Whether $\psi$ is surjective depends on the definition of its codomain. For example, if $n=2$ and $k=1$, the image of $\psi$ is a curve on $\mathbb{R}^2$. So, if the codomain of $\psi$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\psi$ is certainly not surjective.

At any rate, $\psi$ may not be injective even if the origin is not a global minimum. Consider $a=(1,0,0)^T$ and $f(x)=\|x-a\|^2$. Let $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ be the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then $x_H=a$ when $H=\operatorname{span}\{e_1,e_2\}$ or $\operatorname{span}\{e_1,e_3\}$.

Comment: What happens when origin is not the optimal point?

Comment: I agree with your remark on surjectivity. Let $x_{opt} := P^-1q$ denote the global minima of $f(x).$ Let $\mathcal{O} = \{H \in \mathcal{H}: x_{opt} \notin H\}.$ Is $\psi$ injective on $\mathcal{H}\backslash\mathcal{O}?$

Comment: Ok! That also need NOT be true. Suppose that $1 < k < n - 1.$ Let $W$ be a $k + 1$ dimensional subspace. Let $x_W := argmin_{x \in W}f(x).$ One can now clearly choose two distinct $k-$ dimensional subspaces in W, both containing $x_W.$ This now contradicts the fact that $\psi$ is injective.